# get container metrics cpu load

Tags: docker, grafana, metrics, prometheus

i try to get the metrics from my container with grafana and prometheus .

unfortunately i think i make a mistake on my query to get it . When i test my container with jmeter my metric goes until 2% of load however i've 8 pod running .

Even if i watch the monitoring namespace i've 0,03 .

```
topk(3, sum (rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{image!="",container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_namespace="$namespace"}[1m] )) / scalar(count(node_cpu_seconds_total))) *100
```

get the right query ! :)

grafana 5.1.1
prometheus 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

to see the cpu used by my container i use the following query

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_namespace=~"$namespace",container_label_io_kubernetes_container_name=~"^$pod*",container_name!="POD"}[1m]  / scalar(sum(kube_pod_info{namespace=~"$namespace"}) ) * 100
```